# Access firebase/google analytics data in client without going to console

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics

Hello firebasers is it possible to access analytics data on client(app) without going to firebase console?
I need to respond to events in the app offline(in realtime) as they are being triggered. I don't want to listen to analytics event using cloud functions

Example: I want to unsubscribe from a realtime listener when an activity has been opened say 5 times. I want to log the event count and then unsubscribe immediately it reaches 5.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use the right tool for the job?

Comment: Let's say I want to unsubscribe from a realtime listener when say an activity has been opened a number of times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Oct/Nov 2020 there is an [Analytics Data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/trusted-testing/analytics-data) that you can use to run Analytics reports and retrieve data.

I'm not sure if that fits your use-case though, as you seem to want to do more realtime tracking, where Analytics is more focused on aggregating data and then segmenting users into audiences.

If the new API doesn't work, you'll have to track these conditions yourself. For example, in the use-case you give, you'd keep a count of how often the activity has been opened in the application code, and either persist that in local storage, or in an online database (such as the Firebase Realtime Database, or Cloud Firestore) in some data that you associate with that user.